# Calculate how many possible key pairs exist in RSA

Tags: rsa

"Calculate how many possible key pairs exist"

Found these through searching. Not sure if either are correct. I would've assumed the number would be infinite.

phi(n) - 1

phi(n)/2

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @mkad  Welcome to Crypto.SE!  Please say more about what you have understood, and then tell readers where you are stuck.

Comment: @kelalaka yes it is

Comment: From what i can tell, the key pairs are not limited by the n. So the number of key pairs should be infinite. Thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of possible key pairs in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88012/how-to-calculate-number-of-possible-key-pairs-in-rsa)